# How to make a Listbox limits to 3 column in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

Basically, I created a Listbox to record Lab Time for racing purpose. Whenever the car finishes a lap, I hit a Button to record the Lap time.

In my scenario, I only want to record 3 Laps.
(Meaning when I press the button 3 times, it will record all the 3 Laps. Subsequent presses on the button would not display the Lap Time onto the Listbox)

Other than the 3 Laps when I pressed the button I do not want the 4th Lap to appear.

Anyone knows how to limit only 3 Laps?

```
scrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL)
self.m = Listbox(self,selectmode=EXTENDED, height = 5,
                 yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
self.m.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1, pady=5, padx=2)
scrollbar.config(command=self.m.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)


def Lap(self):
    tempo = self._elapsedtime - self.lapmod2
    if self._running:
        self.laps.append(self._setLapTime(tempo))
        self.m.insert(END, self.laps[-1])
        self.m.yview_moveto(1)
        self.lapmod2 = self._elapsedtime
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make a three-column listbox? Or are you asking how to write logic to only allow three clicks of a button?

Comment: Sry i think i got mixed up above. It should be 3 clicks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `self.laps` has three elements, don't add any more elements to it.

```
def Lap(self):
    if len(self.laps) == 3: 
        return
    tempo = self._elapsedtime - self.lapmod2
    if self._running:
        self.laps.append(self._setLapTime(tempo))
        self.m.insert(END, self.laps[-1])
        self.m.yview_moveto(1)
        self.lapmod2 = self._elapsedtime
```